# Comparing Two Uneven List Tuples

Tags: python

I am trying to compare to list tuples and subtract the second value pair ONLY if the first value matches. After this subtraction is done, I would like to keep the tuples that were not in the list. In this case, I would keep ('2574529422', 1).

The code below that I tried returns an empty list. I don't know why it's not working, if allc[0] should be in stmt[0] when it's iterating??

I tried:

```
a = [(allc[0], stmt[1]-allc[1]) for allc,stmt in zip_longest(self.allocation_results, self.statement_results)
             if allc[0] in stmt[0]]
```

input:

```
List 1

[('0856547518', 2), ('1292058151', 5), ('2574529422', 3)]

List 2

[('0856547518', 1), ('1292058151', 3), ('2574529422', 1), ('123456789', 1)]
```

Expected output:

```
[('0856547518', 1), ('1292058151', 2), ('2574529422', 2), ('2574529422', 1)]
```

Comment: Can you show an example input that corresponds to that expected result?

Comment: What is the input? What you have labelled `input` seems to be a single list.

Comment: In your List 2 you have duplicated values `('2574529422', 1)` . Is that intentional?

Comment: @PéterLeéh No should be a different tuple. I have fixed it. Sorry I was just writing it out myself to redact sensitive information.

Comment: Can you post a simple [mre]? There is a `self` in your code without any class

Comment: This needs to be clarified a little bit. Are the two lists ordered the same way? `len(list1) < len(list2)` is always the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the first values of each of your tuples is unique as in your example, you can use them as dictionaries in a list comprehension to get your result:

```
l1 = [('0856547518', 2), ('1292058151', 5), ('2574529422', 3)]
l2 = [('0856547518', 1), ('1292058151', 3), ('2574529422', 1), ('123456789', 1)]

>>> [(k, dict(l1)[k]-dict(l2)[k]) if k in dict(l1) else (k, dict(l2)[k]) for k in dict(l2)]
[('0856547518', 1), ('1292058151', 2), ('2574529422', 2), ('123456789', 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to rearrange a few things to get this to work.

I suspect you had some errors you didn't report.

```py
from itertools import zip_longest

ar = [('0856547518', 2), ('1292058151', 5), ('2574529422', 3)]
sr = [('0856547518', 1), ('1292058151', 3), ('2574529422', 1), ('2574529422', 1)]

def check(allc, stmt):
    if allc is None:
        return True
    return allc[0] == stmt[0]

def make_tuple(allc, stmt):
    if allc is None:
        return stmt
    return allc[0], allc[1] - stmt[1]

a = [make_tuple(allc, stmt) for allc,stmt in zip_longest(ar, sr) if check(allc, stmt)]

print(a)
```

Output as required